# How can I specify UTC Timestamp type in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

I have an Oracle database which I access from my application using NHibernate. The table has a timestamp field. In the code, the corresponding field looks like this:

```
    [Property(Column = "LASTPERFORMED_TS", Type = "Timestamp")]
    public virtual DateTime LastPerformedTs { get; set; }
```

But I need to store UTC timestamp rather than local. Now the default value has local date set by a trigger. Can it be changed to have UTC value by default?

The trigger now does this:

```
:NEW.MODIFIED_TS := SYSDATE;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `DateTimeOffset` as the property type? That at least identifies a precise point in time.

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow should give you the exact Utc datetime with precession of miliseconds.

Comment: I edited my question. Actually, it is about the trigger that sets the default value. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: try using `SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)UTC_SYS, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL; `

Comment: Thanks, it works. If you make it an answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: Done. I posted that as answer below.

Comment: Somewhat related: NHibernate v5 will handle a `TypestampUtc` type. See [NH-2520](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2520).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does not have functions like GETUTCDATE() which returns current UTC date.

In Oracle, you need to use `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` by providing current time stamp of the server to it.

You need to use following to get the current UTC DateTime in Oracle.

```
SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)UTC_SYS, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

This should resolve your issue.